# Can one generate a 'boxed polar plot' with pgfplots and polaraxis?

Tags: pgfplots, polarplot

Sometimes data to be plotted on a polar plot take large values in a specific direction. Is it possible to shape a polar plot created with pgfplots and the polaraxis environment (for example via clipping) so that it looks like the following picture?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pgfplots supports no boxed polar plots of this sort.

You can merely reduce the plotted range using `xmin` and `xmax`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{polaraxis}[
        xmin=0,
        xmax=180,
        ytick distance=0.2,
        yticklabel style={anchor=near yticklabel opposite},
        minor x tick num=2,
        grid=both,
      ]
      \addplot[blue] table {
        0 1
        10 0.7
        20 0.5
        60 0.2
        80 0.25
        90 0.26
        100 0.25
        120 0.2
        160 0.5
        180 1
        };
      \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Christian! That's what I ended up doing at the end. Thanks! (A boxed polar plot would be a nice new feature though.)